# Polling control register of a device in user space to check errors

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, pci, sysfs

I am writing code to log errors in user space occurring on a PCI device(Kernel already logs them in kernel ring buffer). Currently, I have two approaches in front of me,

1. Modify kernel device driver to send an interrupt to my user space process (using eventfd) and then upon receiving this interrupt (using select() or poll()) I can fetch the detailed error information using ioctl (will require a change in device driver). This requires changes in the kernel code which I would like to avoid.
2. My process runs as a root, so, I can read/write error status registers of the device using sysfs. For this, I will have to constantly poll the registers and once the error happens I can read the status register, decode it, get the detailed error information and then clear the registers.

I am more inclined towards the second approach as it requires changes only in the the user space.

My questions are:

1. Does the second approach even make sense?
2. If it does then what are the pros and cons of both the approaches?
3. Polling in second approach will result in wastage of CPU cycles. Does use of select() or poll() in first approach also results in the wastage of CPU cycles in similar proportions.

Helpful response will be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The second approach is an ugly abomination.
   Whether it makes sense in your particular circumstances is something that only you can decide.
2. It is the pupose of a driver to encapsulate and control hardware accesses.
   With the second approach, both the driver and the process might need to be aware that the other might interfere with the device.

   You say that you "would like to avoid" changing the kernel code.
   You don't say why; the reason for that might be reasonable, or not.
3. The driver would waste CPU if it polled the device in a loop.
   With an interrupt, the CPU can sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Read/Write to status register in constant polling mode is not a good idea. Check the function where you read the status register as this is done usually in a critical section, in that case there will be so many lock/unlock during accessing the status register and also the overhead of a system call(a softirq) again and again.

Hence the first Idea of a Driver to send asynchronous events to user-space for error condition is much better approach.